# working with tabindex and multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the order in which certain checkboxes are tabbed to. The problem is, my application can have multiple tabs open, each with the same form. In addition, I have other fields before the checkboxes. How can I change the tab-index of those specific checkboxes without affecting the rest of the inputs in the DOM?

**EDIT:**

Here's the form I'm using.

[image]

The form will start by being focused on the first input (the one with "the last book" as it's value) and should tab normally till you get to the grades. Then it should tab DOWN. Same with the subjects. As you can see, there can be multiple tabs containing this form.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've tried using the tabindex= value, and that it didn't perform what you wanted?

Comment: can you post a sample code of your html, and jquery or link to jsfiddle.

Comment: well, if I set the tabindex to 0 on a checkbox that comes after other inputs, won't the browser tab to it first then? I haven't actually tried it, i was just trying to find the best way to do it.

Comment: here's what I tried. this doesn't even do what I'm wanting. http://jsfiddle.net/KJzrc/1/

Comment: do you want the other inputs to be accessible through tabbing or do you want the cycle to start over with the check boxes once you reach the last checkbox and press tab?  In order to handle the several forms issue, i think you should set a flag on the currently active form tag and then in every input's `onfocus` event check if its parent form has the flag set and if not, just look for the active form, run through its elements and run `focus()` one the element with `tabinex=0`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference between *tab***I***ndex* and *tab***i***ndex* depending on whether it is scripted, or there is a specific content type or browser, or it is set through html directly.

Although I have not tested this myself, I suggest the following:

> **Using tabIndex across browser and content type**
>
> Always use tabindex with lowercase i in markup. See row 1 in table
>   below.
>
> Use tabIndex with uppercase I when setting in script via
>   element.tabIndex. See row 4 in table below.
>
> Check browser and/or content-type when setting in script via
>   element.setAttribute() if is IE or content-type is text/html - set via
>   elem.setAttribute(tabIndex) uppercase. See row 6 in table below.
>
> if is content-type application/xhtml+xml or not IE 6 or 7 - set via
>   elem.setAttribute(tabindex) lowercase. See row 7 in table below
>
> Use lowercase when querying a value using getAttribute(tabindex) that
>   was set in markup as lowercase. See row 9 in table below.
>
> Use lowercase when querying a value using getAttribute(tabindex) that
>   was set directly on element using element.tabIndex uppercase. See row
>   15 in table below.
>
> Setting tabIndex directly on the element using element.tabIndex avoids
>   having to check browser or content type when getting the value.
>
> If the rules above have been followed, use lowercase when querying a
>   value using hasAttribute(tabindex) where available. See rows 25, 31
>   and 33 in table below.

Taken from here: http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2007/11/29/fun-with-the-tabindex-attribute/

Interesting tests on the whole subject may also be found here: http://www.weba11y.com/info/tabindexAccessStrictX10.xhtml